# Cannot Find Dishwasher Leak

Tags: leak, dishwasher

Our dishwasher is leaking and we have checked the hoses underneath and still cannot find the leak. The main white hoses are clear, the black elbow hose is clear, and the motor pump/valve (not sure what it's called) looks clear.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a door seal that is worn out or a crack in the case.

Comment: Protip: If you're going to ask us about your appliance, at least tell us what the heck it is. Even a _brand_ is helpful, but the model is likely staring you in the face every time you open the door.

Comment: Could be the main tub assembly. Typically, the motor, macerator, and pump are mounted to an assembly that is attached to the center of the tub, from below. The whole assembly is removable and has a circular-ish rubber seal to the tub. I had this problem and merely had to remove and grease the seal with silicone plumber's grease to fix it.

Comment: Could be a leak somewhere else and dripping down a pipe or hose.

Answer (score 3):

A trick I use is to line the floor below the dishwasher, then run it. After it has stopped or if your paper is getting wet. Look above the wet spot, that should get you close to the leak.

Comment: This isn't foolproof, as water can drip semi-horizontally along parts, but it can be helpful to narrow things down!  If you have "stuff" above the spot on the floor, you can tie strips of paper towel on various parts to figure out if water is traveling along any of the "stuff."

Answer (score 1):

Gil's suggestion is a good one. I had a 6 year battle with ours, and that strategy helped me find the problem, eventually. *Solving* the problem was a different saga.

I'd look closely at the float assembly for the leak (though it may not be the actual *problem*). Mine was leaking, not because it was faulty but because the drain chopper was broken and main circulation pump was failing. This left too much debris and suds in the cabinet, which overflowed the float tube.

Once I replaced the chopper blade (which is absurdly built with a rust-prone plain steel spring) and then the entire bottom plate assembly (which supports the circulation pump), my float stopped leaking.